# Example of OCRTesseract with OpenCV 3

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, ocr, tesseract

I found that [page](http://cartucho.github.io/d7/ddc/classcv_1_1text_1_1OCRTesseract.html#details) about OCR using Tesseract on OpenCV 3.1. The problem is that given links include examples with older OpenCV versions. Is there any up to date example of usage of OCR Tesseract? and How can I told this to OpenCV authority?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample code below is unfortunately in `Python` with the `text module`/`opencv_contrib`  of `OpenCV 3.2`. I compiled `Tesseract 4.0.0alpha` with `OpenCV 3.2.0` binding to make it works few months ago. Hope this could be a reference for your `C++` implementation.

```
# para: tessdata path, language, whitelist, psm, oem
tesser = cv2.text.OCRTesseract_create('C:/Program Files/Tesseract 4.0.0/tessdata/','eng',
           '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',11,3) 
retval = tesser.run(processed_image, 0) # ' return string type
```

As far as I know, the `Text module` doesn't work well in `OpenCV 3.0/3.1`. Would suggest to use `3.2.0` to avoid any possible issue on earlier `3.x` versions.